# Tcl - Append or Modify a nested list in called function

Tags: tcl, nested-lists, upvar

I have a nested list in the parent function and I want to append a few more elements to it inside one of the called functions

```
proc myparent {
  set mylist {}
  foreach elem $listelements {
     lappend mylist $elem
  }
 
  #at this point, mylist looks something like this:
  # {  {var1 val1} {var2 val2} {var3 val3} }

  myproc1 mylist    #--> want to append mylist here
  
  #myproc1 is expected to add another sublist to mylist. mylist after myproc1 should look like this:
  #  { {var1 val1} {var2 val2} {var3 val3} {abc def} }

  myproc2 $mylist   #--> need to use the updated mylist here
}
```

In myproc1 I want to append some elements to mylist. I tried the following:

```
   myproc1 { {list_var -list} } {
       upvar $list_var list_local
       #some conditional logic
       lappend list_local [list "abc" "def"]
   }
```

But it is not working as expected. Is upvar the right construct to be used for this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to add items to that list stored in the caller is:

```
proc myproc1 {list_var} {
    upvar 1 $list_var list_local

    if {[$I want to add something]} {
        lappend list_local $one_element $another_element
        lappend list_local $a_third_element
    }
}
```

You're recommended to always put the level count in (use `1` in this case) because it enables efficient code generation on at least some versions. It's also clearer. Once you have done the `upvar`, the variable effectively exists in both places at the same time.

If you `lappend` a `list`, you are making a sublist; each argument (after the variable name) to `lappend` becomes an element of its own.

Comment: But `mylist` is a nested list, something like `{ {myvar1 val1} {myvar2 val2} }`  and in myproc1, i want to append another element like `{abc def}`. This is why I used `lappend list_local  [ list "abc" "def"]`

Comment: @dgarg You should edit your question to include a sample list and what the appended one should look like.

Comment: @Shawn edited the question to show sample list and expected appended list

Comment: @dgarg Your myproc1 works for me. Adds a new element, itself a 2-element list, to the end of mylist.

Comment: True. I tried a simple testcase and it works for me as well. But in my full program, i am getting 
`invalid bareword "lappend" in expression "...!= ""
should be "$lappend" or "{lappend}" or "lappend(...)" or ...`

Comment: My mistake.. somehow deleted the closing brace in the if condition before lappend. TCL is so hard to debug for silly mistakes as the errors are cryptic and no line number given.